# Trying to get the periodic restart recycle value of a specific App Pool

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-8, application-pool

- IIS Version: 8.5.9600.16384
- PowerShell version: 4.0

I am trying to get the periodic restart recycle value of a specific apppool like below :

```
$b=(Get-ItemProperty  'IIS:\AppPools\testapppool' -Name `
Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection).value
$b
```

It is giving me output like:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 5
Minutes           : 36
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 201600000000
TotalDays         : 0.233333333333333
TotalHours        : 5.6
TotalMinutes      : 336
TotalSeconds      : 20160
TotalMilliseconds : 20160000
```

If I run:

```
Get-ItemProperty  'IIS:\AppPools\testapppool' -Name`
Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
```

I get output like:

```
value          : 05:36:00

Attributes     : {value}

ChildElements  : {}

ElementTagName : add

Methods        :

Schema         : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

Again when I run below snippet, it give same value output :

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( `
"C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll" )
$serverManager = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
$b=$serverManager.ApplicationPools |where {$_.name -eq 'tetsapppool'}
$var=$b.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.schedule |select time
$var 

Time
----
05:36:00
```

Please help me figuring out a way to assign only the value of the periodic restart recycle value to another variable so that, I can compare it and operate upon the value of the variable.